# Lateral Area of a cone

Tags: area

The lateral area of a cone is $574 \pi$ $cm^2$. The radius is $19.6$ cm. What is the slant height to the nearest tenth of a centimeter?

Comment: What is the formula for the lateral area of a cone?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Hint: you'll probably need to rearrange the formula for lateral area, and replace the r in the formula by the value of radius you were given. You may also need Pythagoras.

Answer (score 0):

$$LA(cone)=\pi r^2+\pi rl$$
where $l$ is the slant height and $r$ the radius. Rearrange for:
$$l=\frac{LA-\pi r^2}{\pi r}=\frac{LA}{\pi r}-r=\frac{574\pi}{19.6\pi}-19.6$$
and go from there.